# Make a FlxSprite sway left and right?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I want to make a FlxSprite object sway left and right at a set speed. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the tweening system (FlxTween).

Here is a tutorial:
[https://haxeflixel.com/documentation/flxtween/]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to tween the object

```
FlxTween.tween(spr, {x: 100}, 1);
```

This tweens the `spr` FlxSprite (can be used to tween any values though) to x position 100, in the duration of 1 second.

To have a sway, you might want to add both an ease to it, and make it `PINGPONG` loop.

```
FlxTween.tween(spr, {x: 100}, 1, {ease: FlxEase.quadInOut, type: PINGPONG});
```

The list of eases can be found in the [FlxTween demo](https://haxeflixel.com/demos/FlxTween/) on the HaxeFlixel website if you wanna see out they all look.

The `type` is the loop type. By default it's set to `ONESHOT`, which plays the tween and keeps it there. `PINGPONG` hits the tween, but then tweens it back to the original position.